# throw new TypeError(`${relative(cwd, fileName)}: Emit skipped`)

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

Hello I have the following typescript code:

```
import { getConnection } from "typeorm";
import { GraphQLClient } from "graphql-request";
import got from "got";
import database from "./utils/database";
...
```

When I execute:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=development ts-node  src/scripts/createApp.ts http://localhost:3010/graphql
```

I get the following error:

```
throw new TypeError(`${relative(cwd, fileName)}: Emit skipped`)
              ^
TypeError: src/scripts/utils/database.js: Emit skipped
```

**database.js**

```
import { createConnection, getConnectionOptions, getConnection } from "typeorm";

export default {
  async connect(): Promise<void> {
    const connectionOptions = await getConnectionOptions(process.env.NODE_ENV);
    await createConnection({
      ...connectionOptions,
      name: "default",
    });
  },
  disconnect(): Promise<void> {
    return getConnection().close();
  },
};
```

Where is the error?, How can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution was set this variable in tsconfig

```
"allowJs": false,
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem but in my case, I needed `allowJs` to be set to `true` in `tsconfig.json` because I do have some auto-generated js-code in my codebase (pre-compiled validators for JSON Schema files) that I need to be included in the output.

The problem was indeed caused by JS files generated by incorrectly compiling TS files to JS files in the same directory. When I cleared my workspace the ts-node began to work properly with both TS files and those few auto-generated JS files.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the tsconfig. I managed to remove rootDir and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

On my side it was due to version after update issue solved

```
yarn add ts-node --dev
# npm i --save-dev ts-node
```